# `PHP Fatal Error: date(): Timezone database is corrupt` on redhat 6.9, nginx, php-fpm

Tags: php, nginx, timezone, redhat

I got an error while calling `date()` on php-fpm.

I know php-fpm works well with `phpinfo()` operates.

I have given permission 777 to `/usr/share/zoneinfo` and `/etc/localtime`. But still not working.

Here's my source code and environemnt.

```
# time.php
<?php
    echo date('r');
?>

# php-fpm error log
[11-Aug-2017 16:18:41] WARNING: [pool www] child 64492 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  strftime(): Timezone database is corrupt - this should *never* happen! in ******time.php in line 2"

# current environment
[root@localhost ~]# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.9 (Santiago)
Release:        6.9
Codename:       Santiago
[root@localhost  ~]# nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.12.0
[root@localhost  ~]# php -v
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Nov  7 2016 11:21:30)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: I don't know it's releated or not. I set network time server for `localhost(server's name)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Reinstalling timezonedb with pecl](http://ivanbayan.com/index.php/2013/06/26/how-to-fix-timezone-database-is-corrupt-this-should-never-happen/) solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling the system timezone database 'stuff' -

```
yum reinstall tzdata
```

Comment: I also try following commands.
`rm -rf /usr/share/zoneinfo`
`yum install tzdata`
But didn't work.